# Why does an empty IP address for fsockopen() on port 80 return a resource

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

I am using `fsockopen()` to check for open ports.  It seems to be working when an active IP address is passed, but seems to always return a resource when the IP address parameter is blank or NULL when using port 80 or 22.  What does this special case mean?

`fsockopen("", 80, $err_code, $err_msg, 1)` returns a resource

`fsockopen("123", 80, $err_code, $err_msg, 1)` returns FALSE

I would expect both to return FALSE.

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect it's defaulting to `localhost`.

Comment: When I try it I get this: `PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: What version of PHP? I tested with 7.4.

Comment: Make sure the port is not used by another software like apache.

Comment: I have tried php 5.6, 7.4, and 8.0, all throw the same error as Barmar.

Comment: I'm using 7.4.  Apache is running so it may be what Barmer and Markus are saying.  It's defaulting to the localhost server (apache)

Comment: Then just stop apache for example with `sudo service apache2 stop` and try again.